# Docker Swarm - Using mongo service only in local enviroment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, docker-stack

So i learned that you can use the same docker-compose file for both local development with docker-machine and for production environment with docker swarm, which is great think, you can also share the same docker-compose file and add specific configuration for production/local enviroment.

One think i couldnt find is a way to define a service only on local enviroment, i have compose file locally which contain redis/node/nginx/mongo containers BUT in production i dont want to use docker for mongo since i use external server(Atlas/ MLab), is it possible to do so and keep using the same files for production & development ?

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose has a solution for the different environment compose files [Multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case). You basically extract the differences into a sub compose file and when running you can merge the compose files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    ...
  node:
     ...
  nginx:
     ...
```

**docker-compose.local.yml**

```
...
services:
  mongo:
     ...
```

When running locally you execute:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d
```

And when deploying to Swarm you just execute:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml
```